# ListView CursorAdapter problems

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I'm working with Java and XML in Android Studio to populate a ListView with CursorAdapter. I'm kinda new to this and trying to solv a problem. I'm really green so any tips would also help.

My DBHandler looks like that:

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 10;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "jogging.db";
public static final String TABLE_TRIP = "Trip";
public static final String TUR_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String TUR_COLUMN_DISTANCE = "Ditance";
public static final String TUR_COLUMN_SCORE = "Fastest";


public DBHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TRIP + "(" +
            TUR_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            TUR_COLUMN_DISTANCE + " TEXT, " +
            TUR_COLUMN_SCORE + " TEXT " +
            ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

CursorAdapter I'm trying to use to get data to ListView:

```
public class TripCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public TripCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
    super(context, cursor, flags);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.content_trips, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView tripId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tripIdView);
    TextView tripDistance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tripDistanceView);
    TextView tripScore = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tripScoreView);

    String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
    String distance = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Ditance"));
    String score = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Fastest"));

    tripId.setText(id);
    tripDistance.setText(distance);
    tripScore.setText(score);
}
```

And the activity to set up ListView

```
public class TripsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DBHandler dbHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trips);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    dbHandler = new DBHandler(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor tripCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Trip", null );

    ListView lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    TripCursorAdapter tripAdapter = new TripCursorAdapter(this, tripCursor, 0);
    lvItems.setAdapter(tripAdapter);
}
```

XML Files:

trips_content.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="hmk.fitness_app.TripsActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_trips">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

And I have also item_trip.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ID"
    android:id="@+id/tripIdView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Distance"
    android:id="@+id/tripDistanceView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Score"
    android:id="@+id/tripScoreView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Not quite sure why I get error msg about null object referances. Any tips what I should do?

Comment: link your xml for content_trips.xml

Comment: set break points on the lines in bindView to observe the values of these objects to identify more information for yourself

Comment: Added the XML files I have used too.

Comment: One issue... you are not using constants to get the values from the cursor you should instead of using strings use constants so you avoid typo errors. The problem i think is happening as well is you are trying to get the '_id' value with String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")); but '_id' is an integer.. you need to make it cursor.getInt instead I believe

Comment: Ok it looks like I didn't really need to set is as an int.

Comment: Ignoring you may have cursor problems. The initial problem is that you are inflating the wrong XML, so you are unable to find that TextView, and it is assigned to null. See the existing answer.

Comment: If you want to set int, float, double, long on TextView cast it to String like tripId.setText(id+"");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.content_trips, parent, false);
```

to

```
return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_trip, parent, false);
```

Comment: Oh duh.. That is it :p